# Cantor set onto connected set?

Tags: gn.general-topology

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space such that the irrationals $\mathbb P$ (in their usual topology) form a dense subspace of $X$.

Let $C$ be the Cantor set.  The set of "non-endpoints" of $C$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb P$.

**Question.** If $f:C\to X$ is a continuous surjection such that $f\restriction \mathbb P$ is the identity map, then is $X$ necessarily disconnected?

NOTE: I suppose we could ask the same question with $\mathbb P$ replaced with the rationals $\mathbb Q$ (identifying the endpoints of $C$ with $\mathbb Q$).

Comment: "The Cantor set" is vague. You probably mean a Cantor subspace of the real line (e.g., the "standard" one), since otherwise the notion of endpoint is senseless.

Comment: Yes.  Or in the $2^\omega$ sense the "endpoints" would mean the eventually constant sequences...

Comment: OK. In any case, in a Cantor set $C$, all countable dense subsets are equivalent up to homeomorphism, the choice of the complement $P$ of one given countable dense subset does not matter.

Comment: But I'm having hard time making sense of your question. It's awkward to identify all embeddings with inclusions.

Comment: So you have the given inclusion $i:P\subset C$, and in addition a dense embedding $j:P\to X$, with $X$ Hausdorff (possibly assuming that $j$ induces a homeomorphism $P\to j(P)$ and that $j(P)$ has countable complement). You suppose the existence of a continuous map $f:C\to X$ such that $f\circ i=j$. Your question seems to be: does it follow that $X$ is disconnected?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: @YCor But to be clear, I do want the particular copy of $\mathbb P$ in $C$ which has countable dense complement.

Comment: The answer is: no. Let $X=[0,1]$ and $P$ the complement of a dense countable dense subset $D$, with $0,1\in P$. So $j$ is the inclusion. Now consider the space $X_D$ obtained from $D$ by doubling (à la Denjoy) all points of $D$. Then $X_D$ is a Cantor set, and comes with a surjective continuous map $p:X_D\to X$ such that fibers of points of $D$ have 2 elements and $p^{-1}(P)\to P$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Btw this is essentially the same as the map mapping a decimal expansion (that's an element of a Cantor set, if we stick to a segment) to the real it defines.

Comment: @YCor What is doubling of points à la Denjoy?

Comment: Check for instance p30 of https://eudml.org/doc/172152 (Keane: *Interval exchange transformations*). Here he doubles all points, but you can glue back all pairs of points outside a countable set of pairs. But again, you have a very natural examples: the map mapping a decimal expansion to the real it defines. It's almost injective, but there are countably manyt fibers of size two (e.g. $734999999\dots$ and $735000000\dots$ which are both mapped to the same real $0.735$), and it maps a Cantor set onto a segment.

Comment: @YCor I see, thanks. May I ask you whether I understand the process correctly? So this doubling seems to be like an "opposite" way of forming the Cantor set: instead of throwing densely countably many open intervals out, you insert densely countably many open gaps at certain places. More precisely, you do this: make a cut at a point of $D$; place the resulting pieces one next to other with a(n arbitrary?) gap between them; close the endpoints; repeat the same once for each point of $D$. Is it this?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე You may have this intuition, even if it's not necessary to really think of the gaps if you don't care about a real embedding for the resulting Cantor set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To rephrase and explicitate YCor's example in the comments, consider the [devil's staircase function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function): it maps the non-endpoints of the standard Cantor set $C$ to the non-dyadic reals in $[0,1]$. Now compose (on the left) with the inverse of the [question mark function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_question-mark_function), which is a self-homeomorphism of $[0,1]$ restricting to an increasing bijection between the dyadics to the irrationals.  The composition $[0,1]\to[0,1]$ is continuous, nondecreasing, its restriction to $C$ is a surjection $C\to[0,1]$ mapping bijectively the set of non-endpoints of $C$ to the set of irrationals in $[0,1]$.